# How to make WinAPI's mouse_event work on a remote machine

Tags: c#, winapi, mstest, ui-automation

I have an automated UI test written in C# (using MSTest) that runs on a remote virtual machine. Parts of this test utilize the user32.dll `mouse_event` method in order to click certain areas of the screen that are not otherwise interactive.

This test works fine when I run it locally, and also when I run it remotely with the agent computer being remotely connected to (via the MSTSC console). The problem is that whenever I completely minimize the MSTSC console (or altogether close it), the mouse actions are not being performed as they should be, and my test fails.

It should be noted that the remote computer runs Caffeine which prevents it from logging off or activating a screensaver - so the tests should run as usual (and the parts that do not involve mouse indeed work just fine).

I reckon this issue has something to do with the mouse being offscreen -- has anyone encountered a similar issue and could offer some help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is due to RDP's default behavior, which locks the remote computer when the remote window is minimized.

I have managed to override this behavior by following the steps described [below](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/user-guide/knowledge-base/test-execution/minimized-rdc.aspx) -- unfortunately this requires modifying the registry on the computer running the MSTSC console. Also, it is not possible to terminate the remote session, otherwise input is again disabled (and I haven't found a documented way to override it as of yet).

To allow remote desktop to be minimized:

1. Open regedit and navigate to the key:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
2. Create a DWORD value with the name RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized and value 2.

On 64-bit OS's, repeat this for the registry key:  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client as well